# Find an function that oscillates between a given upper and lower envelope

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, signal-processing, wavelets

Suppose I'm given two real, continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all real $x$. I'd like to determine an oscillating function $h(x)$ that has $f(x)$ as its upper-envelope and $g(x)$ as its lower envelope. The following image comes from the Wikipedia page titled "Envelope (waves)".

[image]

I'm interested in an open form for the blue function. Thanks for any references or help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is
$$
h(x) = (\sin^2 x) f(x) + (1 - \sin^2 x) g(x).
$$
The function $\sin^2 x$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$, reaching
each extreme once per cycle;
$h(x)$ uses $\sin^2 x$ to interpolate between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$,
so when $\sin^2 x = 0$, $h(x) = g(x)$,
but when $\sin^2 x = 1$, $h(x) = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to have $$h(x)=[f(x)+g(x)]/2+\cos(x) [f(x)-g(x)]/2 $$
You can replace the $\cos(x)$ with any trigonometric function that oscillates between -1 and 1. The first term is the average between the curves, the second contains the distance from the average to each of the curves